# Don't want django makemigration to create a table in database as the I already have the table in the database

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-3.0

I already have a table name `browser` in my database and when I create a new django project and run `python3 manage.py makemigrations` command it adds a new table name `BrowserAddition_browser` in the database. How should I stop django from making a new table and use the current table which is present in the database. Thanks in advance for your help.

This is the model:

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/legacy-databases/

Comment: please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask]